# Graph convolution using a diagonal filter

Tags: fourier-transform, spectral-graph-theory

Given an undirected graph $\mathcal{G} = (V, E)$, if we consider a signal $\bf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ ($x_i =$ value at node $i$-th) and a filter $\bf{g} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then we can define a notion of graph convolution by

\begin{equation}
\bf{x} *_{\mathcal{G}} \bf{g} := \bf{U(U^Tx \, \, \odot U^Tg)}
\end{equation}

where $\odot$ denotes the element-wise product. The thing that I don't understand is, that if we take a filter $\bf{g_\theta = diag(U^Tg)}$, then the above equation becomes

\begin{equation}
\bf{x} *_{\mathcal{G}} \bf{g_{\theta} = Ug_{\theta}U^Tx}
\end{equation}

I guess this follows from some properties of the Hadamard product that I'm ignoring at the moment..

EDIT: adding infos..

$U$ is the matrix of eigenvectors obtained by eigendecomposing the (eventually normalized) Laplacian:

\begin{equation}
L = U \Lambda U^T
\end{equation}

where is defined as $L:= I_n - D^{-1}A$, with $A$ and $D$ the adjacency and degree matrices, respectively.

Comment: What kind of matrix? is $U$? Note that the element-wse product is commutative, switching the order gives you almost what you want but there is an extra $U^T$ in there.

Comment: I've added more details to the question.. yes but the fact that $g_\theta$ is diagonal should be used in some way, I guess...

Comment: Unless I am missing something obvious the dimensions don't add up. $\bf{x}$, $\bf{g}\in\mathbb{R^n}$, $\bf{}g_\theta$$=\text{diag}(\bf{U^T g}$$)\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. The question would be what is $\bf{U^Tx \, \, \odot U^Tg_\theta}$, since the first element is a vector and the second one a matrix. Where is this definition from?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that your graph convolution is given by:

$$ U g(\Lambda) U^\top x = U diag(g(\lambda))U^\top x$$

where $g(\Lambda)$ is a diagonal matrix, containing the **vector** $g(\lambda)$, called sometimes graph frequency response. It turns out that for graph convolutions $g(\lambda)= \Psi g$, where $\Psi$ is a Vandermonde matrix containing powers of the eigenvalues vector $\lambda^k$ in each column and $g$ is the vector containing the $K$ graph filter coefficients. The element-wise multiplication you describe is:

$$U( g(\lambda) \odot U^\top x)$$